# ¿Como soluciono el "error de sintaxis en la clausula FROM" de esta consulta?

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

Hola tengo un problema con el siguiente código en access:

```
SELECT DocumentosGenerados.Id
FROM DocumentosGenerados
LEFT JOIN DocumentosRecibidos 
INNER JOIN Documentos 
INNER JOIN Criterios 
ON DocumentosRecibidos.idCriterio = Criterios.Id
ON DocumentosRecibidos.idDocumento = Documentos.Id
ON DocumentosGenerados.Id = DocumentosRecibidos.DocumentoRespondido;
```

De otras maneras me daba error en el JOIN, o diferentes pero la cosa es que no se como hacer la consulta.

En el SELECT pondré mas campos pero la idea general es la siguiente:

Quiero que me saque todos los documentos generados y pueda acceder al nombre del documento que está en la tabla documentos... la idea es hacer con eso un left join a la tabla documentosrecibidos para que me haga una relación tanto de los que han recibido respuesta como de los que no lo han hecho, y de eso hacer un inner con la tabla criterios que tiene el tipo de respuesta que puede tener un documentorecibido. Para acabar mostrando una lista tipo: DocumentoGenerado, CodigoDestinatario, Contestado el, Valoración.

Supongo que el problema está en los paréntesis pero no hay manera de dar con la disposición correcta.

Edito:

Este código funciona. Lo único que me falta es hacer el left join con las tablas DocumentosRecibidos y Criterios unidas por un inner que es lo que me da error. pongo primero el que funciona:

```
SELECT DocumentosGenerados.Id
FROM (DocumentosGenerados
INNER JOIN Documentos
ON Documentos.Id = DocumentosGenerados.idDocumento)
LEFT JOIN DocumentosRecibidos
ON DocumentosGenerados.Id = DocumentosRecibidos.DocumentoRespondido;
```

Y ahora lo que no, con el error "LA EXPRESIÓN JOIN NO SE ADMITE":

```
SELECT DocumentosGenerados.Id
FROM (DocumentosGenerados
INNER JOIN Documentos
ON Documentos.Id = DocumentosGenerados.idDocumento)
LEFT JOIN (DocumentosRecibidos
INNER JOIN Criterios
ON Criterios.Id = DocumentosRecibidos.idCriterio)
ON DocumentosGenerados.Id = DocumentosRecibidos.DocumentoRespondido;
```

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda, un saludo.

Edito:
Las claves foraneas van asi...
Documentos lleva la principal Id
DocumentosGenerados lleva su principal Id y su foranea a Documentos.Id
DocumentosRecibidos lleva su principal Id, la foranea a DocumentosGenerados, pero también la foránea a Documentos.Id (DocumentosRecibidos.idDocumento), que puede que sea la clave de todo el no ponerla...
Y Criterios que lleva su Id y DocumentosRecibidos hace enlace con DocumentosRecibidos.idCriterio.

Y aqui pregunto si es obligatorio enlazar todas las claves foraneas en la consulta, ya que me interesa saber que documento se responde pero en este caso no con cual contesta (aunque evidentemente ese campo tiene que tener relación con la tabla documentos que es donde aparecen todos los posibles), no se si me explico...

Comment: Empieza por quitar todos los paréntesis en esa consulta, no sirven para nada.

Comment: y tu error? tambien hay que agregarlo a la pregunta

Comment: Gracias, lo edito sin paréntesis entonces. La idea de hacer el left es poder hacer, por ejemplo, que los respondidos aparezcan en verde, los no respondidos en rojo, y en los recibidos tal vez según el criterio que aparezcan en un color distinto. Eso lo haría mediante código vba pero será mas adelante.

Comment: Hola Manny. El error es "ERROR DE SINTAXIS EN LA CLAUSILA FROM". Como digo he cambiado la estructura bastantes veces, y algunas me da el mismo error, otras el error es "EL JOIN NO SE ADMITE"... en esta es el primero. Uso access 2016, y he leído que es tiquismiquis con los paréntesis, y los puse tras consultar foros y por ahí. Pero no consigo que funcione.

Comment: esta mal la sintaxis, simplemente eso.. es join ... on.. join .. on... join.. on.. no es todos los joins y despues los on, porque no sabe donde aplicar cada uno...

Comment: Mmmm... mañana lo probaré. Lo de inner jon on join on lo hice pero es cuerto que en lugar de poner solo join ponía inner join otra vez. No obstante probé la sintaxis en MySql y funcionaba. Era pasarlo a access y saltarme el error. En esa ocasión era elde "el join no se admite". Pero lo probaré con solo joins los siguientes y os digo lo que sea. Muchas gracias

Comment: access no es mysql.. es otra base de datos.. y mysql admite varias cosas que no son ansi sql (o sea que otras bases no admiten). Tene en cuenta eso...

Comment: Voy a editar, ya que tengo un problema a la hora de hacer el inner join después del left join (he leido que en access no se pueden anidar inner dentro de left... pero no se como hacerlo sino). Lo dicho voy a editar a ver si alguien tiene alguna idea.

Comment: Ah, le di like a A. Cedano por el comentario de que los paréntesis no sirven para nada, pero revisé recién un par de consultas de Access que tengo y una lleva paréntesis así como en tu primera consulta que funciona. Por algo le habré puesto yo.

Comment: Si... además por lo que se ve no deja hacer inners después del left, y tienen que ser todos left o right. Es una castaña. Lo estoy haciendo con la consulta que genera el propio access con el diseñador de consultas pero no tengo muy claro que es lo que hace, además he añadido mas tablas y es todo un poco mas complejo :(

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un poco de lio en el orden de las sentencias. Debes poner la clausula `ON` justo después del `JOIN` y la tabla que unes debe estar declarada antes.

```
SELECT DocumentosGenerados.Id
FROM DocumentosGenerados
INNER JOIN Documentos ON Documentos.Id = DocumentosGenerados.idDocumento
LEFT JOIN DocumentosRecibidos ON DocumentosGenerados.Id = DocumentosRecibidos.DocumentoRespondido
INNER JOIN Criterios ON Criterios.Id = DocumentosRecibidos.idCriterio;
```

Comment: Hola. En esta consulta el error es: "ERROR DE SINTAXIS, FALTA OPERADOR en la expresión de consulta Documentos.Id = DocumentosGenerados.idDocumentos... (toda la consulta)"  :(

Answer (score 0):

Me respondo a mi mismo con la consulta que genera access con todas las tablas puestas, y asi me la deja. Creo que voy a quedarme con esto aunque no estoy muy seguro de que sea lo que busco jaja, se verá cuando empiece a meterle datos a la cosa. Esta es la solución que me da access:

```
SELECT DocumentosGenerados.Id AS idDocGen, Tramites.NombreTramite, Entidades.Nombre AS Destinatario, Documentos.TipoDocumento, DocumentosGenerados.FechaEnvio, 
DocumentosGenerados.FechaRecepcion, Criterios.NombreCriterio, DocumentosRecibidos.idCriterio, DocumentosRecibidos.FechaEntrada AS FechaContestacion
FROM (Tramites AS Tramites_1 
RIGHT JOIN (Entidades AS Entidades_1 
RIGHT JOIN ((TipoTramitesExpediente 
INNER JOIN (Tramites 
INNER JOIN (Entidades 
INNER JOIN (Documentos INNER JOIN DocumentosGenerados ON Documentos.Id = DocumentosGenerados.idDocumento) ON Entidades.Id = DocumentosGenerados.idEntidad) 
ON Tramites.Id = DocumentosGenerados.idTramite) 
ON TipoTramitesExpediente.Id = Tramites.TipoTramite) 
LEFT JOIN (Documentos AS Documentos_1 
RIGHT JOIN (Criterios RIGHT JOIN DocumentosRecibidos ON Criterios.Id = DocumentosRecibidos.idCriterio) 
ON Documentos_1.Id = DocumentosRecibidos.idDocumento) 
ON DocumentosGenerados.Id = DocumentosRecibidos.DocumentoRespondido) 
ON Entidades_1.Id = DocumentosRecibidos.idEntidad) 
ON Tramites_1.Id = DocumentosRecibidos.idTramite) 
INNER JOIN Expedientes 
ON (Expedientes.IdExpediente = Tramites.idExpediente) AND (Entidades.Id = Expedientes.idTitular);
```